# Data from table not appearing on ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Very simply I have data in a table on a server that does not appear when my ASP.NET MVC page is compiled into HTML.

I know everything on the backend works, because on other views there is no issue, but for some reason on this one page it doesn't work.

I suspect it has something to do with my model having two classes in it, because this is the only page to do that, but I'm not really sure as I am a novice at MVC.

Here's the Model, which I'll refer to as **ModelFile.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Project.Subgroup.Models
{
    public class ClassIActuallyNeed
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Html { get; set; } //<---This is the data I want
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }


    }

    public class ClassMyFriendInsistsINeed
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] Signature { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }

        public virtual ClassIActuallyNeed ClassIActuallyNeed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

...and the Controller which is called **MainController.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Project.Models;
using Project.Subgroup.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Project.Models.Authentication;

namespace Project.Subgroup.Controllers
{
    public class MainController : Controller
    {
        private MyDatabase context = new MyDatabase();

        // GET: Lobby/Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult FormPage()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FormPage(ClassIActuallyNeed model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var context = new MyDatabase())
                {
                    var modelfile = new ModelFile
                    {
                        Name = model.Name,
                        Signature = model.Signature,
                        ClassIActuallyNeedId = model.ClassIActuallyNeedId
                    };
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

...and finally the view, which is **FormPage.cshtml**:

```
@model Project.Models.ClassIActuallyNeed

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Page";
    Layout = "~/Subgroup/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2 >@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Html) //<---- the problem

    //There is other form stuff in here
}
```

The "Html" data is literally just a string containing HTML that I want plopped into my webpage. It's the only line in that table, and when I use "DisplayNameFor" instead of "DisplayFor", it successfully puts the name "Html" on my page.

Sorry for the code vomit, I cut out everything I knew was unrelated but I just can't really pin down exactly where my problem is. There are no errors of any kind in visual studio or in the console. Everything else on the page works totally fine including my JS stuff.

**Edit:** I appreciate all the input so far. I know that the problem is not that I don't have the model populated, as it is populated by the remote database. This works on every other page.
As I suspected the RequestVerificationToken is definitely supposed to be there, and is unrelated.

Also to clarify: the issue is not that it is displaying unformatted text instead of HTML. The issue is that it is displaying nothing at all.

Comment: Where do you put any data in your model to be displayed?  Which action method are you calling?  Your POST method for `FormPage` doesn't really do anything.  It opens a database connection that it never uses, creates an object that it never uses, and then returns whatever was sent to it.

Comment: as @David said, in the GET controller action that loads your page, youre not populating your model. Also, as your view code currently stands, you will have the `Html` string rendered on the page as text and not actually rendered as html. To have the html string actually rendered, you need to use `Html.Raw()`. Be careful that no one can inject malicious scripts into your page (in case a user is capable of saving html string data into this property) but this is getting out of the scope of your post

Comment: @Thomas in response to your edit, I'm not sure how else I can put this but you're not seeing any data because you're not giving the view any data. Your edit states that a "remote database" is populating the model however that isnt something that just magically happens and no where in your code is the model populated. In fact, since your view is razor, you can set a breakpoint on your `DisplayFor` line and you'll see that your model is null... because it's not being populated!

Comment: If the above is untrue, then youve made an error when you translated your actual code into the example you posted in your question and we need an actual example that fully replicates your issue to help you

Comment: I'll try that. Like I said I'm a novice at MVC (and databases for that matter). I guess what confuses me then is not why this one doesn't work, but why other ones do? It seems like it "magically" populates the other pages for lack of a better term. My understanding was that when you put the line setting the Database context that all the getters and setters find the right keys when called. I do appreciate the help though, I'll go toss some breakpoints and see what I can.

Comment: @ThomasRosebrough no problem, in an effort to clear things up: `private MyDatabase context = new MyDatabase();` will create a context that you can use to retrieve data. In your posted code, you're never using the context to get any data and hand it over to your view. it's hard for me to say why anything else works without being able to see it. I'll edit my answer a bit more to show a simple example of getting data from the context and giving it to your view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 issues currently that I can see:

- You're not populating your model with any data

  ```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult FormPage()
  {
      //you need to pass the view some data, otherwise your model in your view
      //will be null and you wont get any output (which is what you're seeing now)

      ClassIActuallyNeed model = null;

      //hardcoded:
      //model = new ClassIActuallyNeed
      //{ 
      //    Id = 1, 
      //    Html = "<h1>Hello</h1>", 
      //    Version = "something, 
      //    Deleted = false
      //};

      //an example of using your context to fetch your model
      using(var context = new MyDatabase())
      {
          var id = 1
          model = context.ClassIActuallyNeeds.Single(x => x.Id == id);
      }

      return View(model);
  }
  ```
- You're not rendering the html string as html

  `Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Html)` will render the this property as plain text on the page so instead of seeing `Hello` formatted in a `<h1>` tag, you'll see `<h1>Hello</h1>` as plain text on the page. The framework does this to protect against injection attacks which I'd suggest you read up on a bit however that's out of scope as far as this post goes. To have the html string actually rendered, use `Html.Raw(model => model.Html)`

As an additional side note, the 
`<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="[a bunch of junk characters here]">`
you're seeing is a result of you using a `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`. The antiforgery token is used to protect against CSRF attacks which I'd also suggest you read up on (security is important!). Since this view does not have any editable data in it (that's an assumption I'm making based on you using `DisplayFor`), there's no reason I see to have a form (`Html.BeginForm`) in your view or a AntiForgeryToken. If this data is editable and can be posted back to the server, then disregard that and both of those 2 pieces likely need to stay in place.

With the controller action above, your view could simply look like the following to display your data:

```
@model Project.Models.ClassIActuallyNeed

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Page";
    Layout = "~/Subgroup/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2 >@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@Html.Raw(model => model.Html)
```

If this data needs to be editable then it would look more like

```
@model Project.Models.ClassIActuallyNeed

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Page";
    Layout = "~/Subgroup/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2 >@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Version)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Deleted)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Html)

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
}
```